# Erro de autenticação ao enviar arquivo para repositório no Github

Tags: git, github, bash

Bom segui os passo desse [link](http://gabsferreira.com/criando-e-enviando-arquivos-para-seu-repositorio-no-github/), porém quando chego no `git push -u origin master` ele pede o usuário e senha do git em um windows forms, depois pede o usuário (2 linha), e pede a senha do SSH sendo que eu nem configurei essa senha e estou usando o https. A chave do SSH está criada.

```
Fatal: AggregateException encountered.
Username for 'https://github.com': letarzan
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/LeTarzan/TCC.git/'
```

O que pode ser?

Git remove -v:

```
origin  https://github.com/LeTarzan/TCC.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/LeTarzan/TCC.git (push)
```

Comment: já tentou passar o email do github?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Com HTTPS você usar a sua senha de login no git. Veja [está pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909221/why-is-github-asking-for-username-password-when-following-the-instructions-on-sc)

Comment: Acabei de descobrir que era a versão, atualizei e funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Pode existir diferentes motivos para este erro:

- Seu usuário ou senha está incorreto. Para garantir, remova suas credenciais de acesso ao Github no Windows via Gerenciador de Credenciais e tente novamente.
- Você ativou o *two-factor authentication* na sua conta do Github. Neste caso você precisa gerar um [token de acesso](https://github.com/settings/tokens).
- Você não é um colaborador do repositório.

Em alguns casos pode ser algum problema de configuração do Git instalado na sua máquina. Uma instalação limpa ou atualização de versão do Git pode resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta fazer isso:

```
$ git config --global user.name seu_nome_de_usuario
$ git config --global user.email seu@email.com
```

Se não funcionar, como está usando HTTPS, tenta verificar se a senha que tu tá digitando bate com a senha do teu remoto.